# CCSequence causes app to run out of memory when given too many CCActions

Tags: ios, cocos2d-iphone

I am using Cocos2d to create animations in an iPad app.

In the app, the user can create a sequence of animations and choose how many times that sequence will repeat. For unrelated reasons I chose to split up each action in to many small actions- i.e. if the user chooses to move 100pts she will instead move 2pts 100 times. This can lead to very large CCSequence arrays.

I have found that creating a sequence of about 16k CCActions causes the app to crash. Is this the expected behavior? Does anyone know of a workaround to achieve this effect or do I need to end the splitting up of movements?

Thanks!

Edit: Here's a screenshot depicting the effect I want to achieve and the reason I am splitting up my animation. 
[image]

Comment: Uh, that sounds terribly wasteful. Why would you want to move objects 2 points at a time? If you need that, why don't you move it in the update method, adjusting position? That's a lot more efficient.

Comment: @LearnCocos2D I have a feature where when an object moves you can toggle whether to draw a line behind it. The line needs to accurately follow the movement (so if you move 4, turn off the line, move 4, repeat it will look like an evenly dotted line). The line also needs to sync up with the movement- meaning I couldn't just specify the line beforehand and have it draw. I couldn't achieve the accuracy I desired with small distances unless the animation and the line were moving in tandem- so move 2, draw line 2 etc. Any advice?

Answer (score 0):

```
typedef enum Actor_STATE{
    kState_MovingLeft = 14001,
    kState_MovingRight
}ActorState;


@interface HorseRider : CCSprite
{
    ActorState mState;
    float mMoveSpeed;
}
@property(nonatomic, assign) ActorState     state;

//implementation of HorseRider

-(void)updateRider
{
    CGPoint pos = self.position;

    if(self.state == kState_MovingLeft)
    { 
        pos.x -= mMoveSpeed;

        if(pos.x>screenWidth)
        {
           state = kState_MovingRight; 
           continue;
        }
    }
    else 
    { 
       pos.x += mMoveSpeed;

        if(pos.x>0.0f)
        {
           state = kState_MovingRight; 
           continue;
        }

        [self createTrackDots];

    }

    self.position = pos;
}

-(void) createTrackDots
{
   if(ABS(lastDots.x - self.position.x) > MIN_DOT_DISTANCE)
   {
      [self createDotsAtPos: self.position]; 
   }
}


//Game init
-(id)init
{
    …
    hero = [HorseRider spriteWithSpriteFrameName:FRAME_NAME];
    hero.state = kState_MovingLeft;
    ….
    [self schedule: @selector(tick:)];
}


-(void) tick: (ccTime) dt
{    
   if(self.isGamePaused || self.isGameOver )
    {
        [hero updateRider];
    }


}
```

Comment: Thanks Raj, good to know. I think the problem I'm experiencing is slightly different because it has to do with the CCSequence overflowing (which happens before I have too many CCAction objects).

Comment: @SamanthaJohn, ok updated my answer...based on suggestions from LearnCocos2D in question:)